# place custom posts as submenus in wordpress admin area's menu

Tags: menu, wordpress-theming, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created several custom posts and added them to the menu sidebar, however since it is for a client I would like to make it a little more neat and easier to navigate by dividing those custom posts by their "category" (not in wordpress terms).

What I need is to create menu items that have as submenu several custom posts. How can I do that?

as an exemple, now the menu looks like this:

```
> dashboard

> post

> page

> media

> custom post #1

> custom post #2

> custom post #4

> custom post #5

> settings

... etc.
```

what I want to achieve is instead this:

```
> dashboard

> post

> page

> media

> boats
    > custom post #1
    > custom post #2

> cars 
    > custom post #3
    > custom post #4

> bikes
    > custom post #5

> settings

... etc.
```

Can you show me how to do it? The plugins I tried only allowed me to add separators. Plus I like to write, learn and know my own code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- [create a plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/where-do-i-put-the-code-snippets-i-found-here-or-somewhere-else-on-the-web) to do it
- use the functions [`add_menu_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) and [`add_submenu_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) to create the menus
- [point the submenus](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/75411/12615) to specific post edit screens
- [use some jQuery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/59062/12615) to manipulate this non-standard way of menu/submenu items